# Inventor Core Engine Core Console is shut down due to timeout

Tags: autodesk-designautomation

I am having problems processing a file that works fine when hosting the plugin on the desktop, but fails when hosted on Forge:
[image: Forge output]

Note that the time-out is triggered after one minute exactly after processing. This reminded me of an earlier problem we had:
[previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66297786/an-unexpected-error-happened-during-phase-coreengineexecution-of-job)

That was solved by implementing the heartbeat. Running this file locally generates heartbeats:
[image: heartbeats]

Given we have heartbeats, are there any other mechanisms that generate a timeout after 60 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely correct. The problem you are experiencing is connected to missing heartbeats. It is not clear why is your heart beating not visible in the first log, since you say you are using it, but the fact that it is not visible is causing the timeout. It might be your heartbeat tread is not started or paused or you are performing so processing intensive operation, that the console (stdout) is frozen and does not take the heart beating message.